# Bazaar CVS (bzr) with proxy (socks using tor)

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, bazaar, tor, bazaar-plugins

I (on ubuntu) need to use bzr behind institute's proxy which restricts bzr to connect.So, is there anyway to connect it through socks proxy obtained by tor(vidalia) as i am not able to successfully setup polipo with tor to get http proxy instead.

Answer (score 1):

bzr honors the `http_proxy` environment variable. Try setting:

```
set http_proxy=http://localhost:3128/
```

Or something along those lines.